# Changing textView in java code causing crash/not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview, widget

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String test = "test";
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setText(test);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

The problem started in a fragment, I tried all StackOverflow solutions to no avail so I made a fresh build and now I'm just trying to make it work in MainActivity. Can someone please explain why this code does not update the textView, and why it is caushing a crash.

Note: I have tried making my own setText() methods, i've tried using strings and char arrays from other safer locations, I've moved the code before and after setContentView(), and if its just another way of coding the above^ in a different way, I've probably tried it. Pretty much each thing I try leads to the same result. This leads me to believe the solution isn't just in the code above, but something else overlooked, and probably a simple fix. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my xml, my freshman CS senses tingle seeing the android:text="" line.

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

Comment: You have to call `setContentView()` _before_ you try to find `View`s in its layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code You must call the setcontentView method before calling findViewById method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
String test = "test";
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
text.setText(test);


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, tried the code after setContentView(), still causes app to stop. Would posting any of the crash log help?

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: Hold up, now it's working, my previous comment was a result of using that fix on the non-fresh build. Thanks for the help, do you have an idea why the code wouldn't work in a fragment? Aka would I have to change something around the setContentView, even though thats not where the actual code is?

Comment: Fragment is not an activity if you want to use fragment   View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutName, container, false);
       TextView  text= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textviewID); text.setText("some");

Comment: Boom, solved. For the record, I was relying on using getView().findViewById() and simply returning the inflater itself rather than creating and returning a View which equals the inflater.